# Unknown Issue using Samsung phones

Tags: android, performance, web-services, android-wifi, galaxy

I have developed an application in android. The application consists of server and client interaction via webservice. I have checked the wifi connectivity status, if the connectivity status is false i have shown attention box and if connectivity status is true i will perform some action. But the issue i have experienced is the attention box is shown on LG,Sony and other smartphones except SAMSUNG all models including galaxy S4.

Can anyone know about this......

I will post the code below which checks wifi,4g and status.

```
boolean connected = false;
     ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
             connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED||
             connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
        {
     // some action
            //we are connected to a network
            connected = true;
        }
    if(connected == false){
    //      System.out.println("The Network error");
            attentionBox("There is no network connection right now. Please try again later.","Internet Connection Error"); 
        }
```

and attention box coding is :

```
 public void attentionBox(final String msg, final String title)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewYourPlanList.this);
        builder.setMessage(msg)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ((AlertDialog)dialog).getButton(which).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                         //finish();  
                         System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: can u share attentionBox coding

Comment: peter i shared. it works in all other mobiles except samsung ????

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
    public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
       ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: i tried the above coding which you have posted but for some reason 4G is not supported hence i changed my logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me

```
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);


    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

If it is useful for you. vote for me.

Comment: May i know what is wrong with my coding in alertDialog....I am asking this, because i want to know the error ??? as you said i will try your code...and i will test in all platforms

Comment: can u share your log cat

Comment: dude it's not working...and first of all i am testing in real device not on emulator....and when i run the app in emulator no error....the code works fine and attention box is shown on all devices....i checked with my friends mobile...but the issue is the app crashes when i run my app in SAMSUNG devices namely (Galaxy S4,Samsung icore 8262,etc...)